# CSS content:url is not working in internet explorer 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Back arrow hyperlink's image is rendering properly in chrome but not in internet explorer 11, however I am able to click on it, even from ie (mouse cursor is changing from arrow to hand, when I move the cursor to its respected position in ie11).

Below is my html code --

```
<a href="path/xyz.jsp" class="backlink"></a>
```

Below is my css code --

```
.backlink {
content: url(back/back.png);
padding-right: 5px;
vertical-align: middle;
```

}

In chrome back.png is displaying like below --

[image]

Please help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `content:` on regular elements is not yet fully supported.

`content:` is intended for use with pseudo element, such as `before`, and `after`.

Chrome, has likely started to implement some of the CSS working draft (where it has been suggested that `content` work on 'regular' elements too.

Comment: Thanks @Stuart. I tried with 'before' and it worked!!

Comment: Thanks @Stuart, you saved me with this, I used :after, and IE11 loaded my svgs via a content url in my style sheet.

Comment: Thanks, I was struggling with IE11.